# 'node' is not recognized as an internal or external command - a path issue

Tags: node.js, path, windows-7

This question has already been asked but the solutions were not enough for me.
I heve windows-7. when I run 'node -v' in order to check if it installed, it give me this message:

```
'node' is not recognized as an internal or external command
```

I added it to the path:

```
 C:\Program Files\nodejs
```

and it still not work, even after restart.
There is another option - to run this on the command line:

```
SET PATH=C:\Program Files\Nodejs;%PATH%
```

it does work, but I have to run this every time I open the command line, and it is quite annoying, especially that I heve another paths that are not recognized
and the 'SET PATH=...' does not work for them.
this is my path:

```
C:\Program Files\nodejs ;
C:\Windows\System32\  ;
C:\Program Files\Git;
C:\Program Files (x86)\PostgreSQL\10;
C:\Users\nathan-hp\AppData\Roaming\npm
```

I also tried to uninstall and then install.
I guess I am doing something wrong with the path

Comment: add semicolon ";" at the end of the path while adding the path in environment variable.

Comment: thanks, but I did it as you can see in the end of my question

Comment: okay. Did you run this command "SET PATH=C:\Program Files\Nodejs;%PATH%" in administrator mode? if not, try that.

Comment: I did that, but when I reopen the command line in the regular mode, it still not recognize it and I have to run it again

Comment: Which version of node.js are you using? If you are using older version try to install the newer version and set the path. If that does not work, I think your system needs a restart and repeat the steps post that. Hope that works!

Comment: I have 12.16.1, I will try this, thanks

Comment: it worked, thanks !

Answer (score 1):

The other alternative is using **setx** command but, use it with care as it permanently updates the environment variables:

```
setx /M PATH "%PATH%;<new-path>"
```

/m -  This sets the variable in the system environment variable